# Uploading large files from nodejs to another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, node-webkit

I have a desktop app that uses node webkit, and I need the ability to upload large files from the node server to another server. It needs to be able to chunk the files to the server, as there is a request size limit that prevents streaming the entire file. I'm currently using the request module to post uploads without chunking, which works fine for small files, but I can't seem to find any examples of how you would do chunked uploads from node. The following is what I have at this point:

```js
var form = request.post('http://server.com/Document/Upload',
    {contentType: 'multipart/form-data; boundary="' + boundaryKey + '"', preambleCRLF: true, postambleCRLF: true},
    function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(res);
    }).form();

form.append('uploadId', myUploadId);
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(zipFileFullPath), {filename: 'test.zip'});
```

Any idea how I would accomplish this in node? I've seen plenty of examples of receiving chunked uploads on a node server, but can't seem to find anything on how to send them from node.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've shown?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't chunk files, so when I send a file that exceeds size of the max request length on the server it fails.

Comment: If that's the case, how were you expecting to "chunk" the file? Multiple requests somehow?

Comment: Yes, that's generally the idea, sending multiple requests with transfer-encoding of 'chunked'. There are several libraries available that do this on the client side, but they require the user to select the file from a file input or through drag and drop, whereas I need to do this from node because the file is a zip that's being created in node.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) it shows how to supply the chunked option:

```
request({
    method: 'PUT',
    preambleCRLF: true,
    postambleCRLF: true,
    uri: 'http://service.com/upload',
    multipart: [
      {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
        body: JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar', _attachments: {'message.txt': {follows: true, length: 18, 'content_type': 'text/plain' }}})
      },
      { body: 'I am an attachment' },
      { body: fs.createReadStream('image.png') }
    ],
    // alternatively pass an object containing additional options 
    multipart: {
      chunked: false,
      data: [
        {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          body: JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar', _attachments: {'message.txt': {follows: true, length: 18, 'content_type': 'text/plain' }}})
        },
        { body: 'I am an attachment' }
      ]
    }
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', error);
    }
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  })
```